# Should I consider any other tools outside the Apple development tools for iPad development?

Tags: ipad

The [Apple dev site](http://developer.apple.com/programs/iphone/develop.html) makes it look as tho it has all the tools you want for developing iPad apps.  Should I consider any other tools outside the Apple development tools for iPad development?

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Comment: There are some possible problems with outside tools based on the new developer agreement: http://daringfireball.net/2010/04/iphone_agreement_bans_flash_compiler

Comment: Oh if only there were that were legal in the world according to Apple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MonoTouch is another option, if you're a .NET developer looking to do iPhone/iPad development. (Currently MonoTouch has experimental, alpha-level support for iPad, but full support shouldn't be far away.) It's not free, but it's a great tool if you're coming from that background.

Plus it compiles to native code for the iPhone, so can be used for App Store builds and everything.

Comment: MonoTouch is probably banned now.

Comment: I was just going to say the same thing.  Apple are running a more closed shop than MS, and it absolutely stinks.  Then they have the cheek to ban Flash based on the fact that it is 'proprietary technology'.  Deeply cynical practises that are basically engineered to maximise profits.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe has some tools where you can author in Flash/Flex/Air and it will compile down into a valid iPhone/iPad application, that can be accepted and sold in the appstore.

There's also a company called Unity3D http://unity3d.com/unity/features/iphone-publishing.html that has some alternative iPhone/iPad development tools (where you program in C#!)

Comment: Adobe are terminating support for this now, given the restrictions Apple have placed on development as mentioned by wesleydyson.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of tools you're talking about... If you mean applications, you can use any editor you want for example, like TextMate or Vim or anything else (personally, I hate Xcode's built-in editor, it can't even open files in tabs...). You'll still need to use Xcode for building the app and IB for preparing the interfaces though (unless you want to create entire UI in code, which is madness). I'm not aware of any unofficial tools that can build an iPhone app or create NIB interface files.

If you mean frameworks that allow you to code in something else than ObjC (like Adobe's Flash tools or MonoTouch), then these were recently banned by Apple, so you need to stick to the standard ObjC/Cocoa APIs.